# show that for an infinite cardinal $k$, $k + k = k$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Show that for an infinite cardinal $k$, $k + k = k$

So far I have that $k + k = 2k$

Is it possible to somehow show that $2k = k$?

I've been trying to understand some cardinal arithmetic, and I know that if you have two disjoint sets $S,T$ with $|S| = m$ and $|T| = n$ then $ mn = |S \times T|$

but I don't know what do do when it's just an integer.

Comment: You have to use the axiom of choice, so there's no way to actually write down a formula for such bijection. I think this was covered a few times before, and I'm looking for a duplicate.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can also add what you know or don't know about *infinite* sets.

Comment: I know the axiom of choice, if that helps.

Comment: Would you perhaps define a choice function from $2k$ to $k$?

Comment: Do you know that every cardinal is an ordinal, and some basic properties of ordinals? Do you know what Zorn's lemma is? Do you know that for infinite ordinals it holds that $|\alpha|^2=|\alpha|$?

Comment: Is it possible to give me a link to resources explaining this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. I couldn't quite find a duplicate, so I'll write an answer instead. I will sketch the idea, and give some of the details. The rest I leave to you.

First we need to understand what $2k=k$ means. It means that if $K$ is a set such that $|K|=k$, then $\{0,1\}\times K$ and $K$ have the same cardinality. You can easily see that $\{0,1\}\times K=\{0\}\times K\cup\{1\}\times K$, and this is the disjoint union of two sets of cardinality $k$.

For example, $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$ (where $\aleph_0=|\Bbb N|$).

Next we are going to need the following fact: $K$ is infinite if and only if there is a countably infinite subset of $K$. Or in other words, $\aleph_0\leq k$.

As well one of its consequences, if $K$ is infinite and $A$ is finite, then $|K\setminus A|=|K\cup A|=|K|$.

---

Now we can use Zorn's lemma, which states that every partial order $(P,\leq)$ in which every chain has an upper bound has a maximal element.

We define the partial order on pairs of the form $(A,f)$ where $A\subseteq K$ is infinite and $f$ is a bijection from $\{0,1\}\times A$ onto $A$. Since $K$ is infinite it has countably infinite subsets, all of which has such $f$'s, so this partial order is certainly not empty.

We say that $(A,f)\leq(B,g)$ if $A\subseteq B$ and $f\subseteq g$, meaning $A$ is a subset of $B$ and if we restrict $g$ to $\{0,1\}\times A$ we get $f$.

Finally, if $\{(A_i,f_i)\mid i\in I\}$ is a chain, then I claim that $A=\bigcup A_i$ and $f=\bigcup f_i$ are such that $(A,f)$ is in the partial order. Certainly $A$ is infinite. Let us see that $f\colon\{0,1\}\times A\to A$ is a bijection:

1. First of all, $f$ is a function since it is the increasing union of functions.
2. For the same reason it is injective. If we have $t,t'\in\{0,1\}$ and $a,a'\in A$ and suppose that $f(t,a)=f(t',a')$. There is some $i\in I$ where $a,a'\in A_i$ and therefore $f_i(t,a)=f(t,a)=f(t',a')=f_i(t',a')$, but $f_i$ is injective so we have that $t=t'$ and $a=a'$.
3. And again this is a surjection, since if $a\in A$ there is some $i$ such that $a\in A_i$, and I will let you finish the argument from here.

Now, to finish the proof you have to show that the maximal element is $(K,f)$. But this might not be true. You can prove, however, that if $(K',f')$ is a maximal element then $K\setminus K'$ is *finite*. If it were infinite, you could have found a way to extend it beyond its maximality.

So we return to the consequence of the infinitude of $K$, and we have that $|K|=|K'|$ and therefore $2k=k$.