# For infinite cardinal $\kappa$, $\kappa$ . $\kappa$ = $\kappa$ . Set Theory Enderton p-162, Lemma 6R

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

Enderton's proof goes like below;

Let B be any infinite set of cardinality $\kappa$.

Let $H=${$f|f=$$\emptyset$ or $f: A×A-A$ is a bijection for some A $\subseteq B$}

Then he showed that any chain in H has upper bound in H. Hence H has a maximal element, $f_o$. That's fine I have no problem upto this.

But then he tells that the maximal element $f_o$$:A_o×A_o$ $-A_o$ is a bijection, for some $A_o$ $\subseteq B$. The maximal element $f_o$ might not be a bijection from $B×B$ onto $B$, instead for big enough subset  $A_o$ $\subseteq B$, $f_o$$:A_o×A_o$ $-A_o$ is a bijection. I am unable to comprehend, why should the transfinite process stop at some $A_o$ $\subseteq B$ instead taking whole B. Can someone explain this point with an expository explanation? (Edit: Here I mainly wanted to get an intuition that how the transfinite recursion process will work in general rather than a formal proof)

My guess: For $B=\omega +2$, we might be stop at $A_o=\omega$. But I don't have any insight into **the process**. Why might we stop at $A_o$.

====================================

There is similar question already here.

[show that for an infinite cardinal $k$, $k + k = k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828529/show-that-for-an-infinite-cardinal-k-k-k-k)

I understand the Enderton's proof, as well as Asaf's proof. But I am unable to understand the point in Asaf's proof(link of the Asaf's proof given above)/the same point in Enderton's proof that "Why $(K,f)$ might not be a maximal element of the partial order mentioned in the Asaf's proof?"

It would be best, if I asked this in comment below Asaf's answer but I don't have enough reputation to comment. So if someone explain this to me, I will be thankful.

Comment: If you take K any set of cardinality greater than $\aleph_o$, then F need not to be finite.
Still unable to understand from your answer why should the process start at K-F?

Comment: Notation: It is standard to write $f:C\to D$ (code f:C\to D ) instead of $f:C- D.$

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I will write in future. I am new to here. I haven't used latex since long time. So I forget many of the codes.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet and @ That's Life Please look at my answer, I have expanded it.

Comment: On this site, if you right-click on someone's math and hover over "Show Math As" and slide over to "Tex Commands", and left-click, then it will show you their code. This is often a quick way to find code.... BTW the code for $\nabla$, which is called "del", is \nabla... I dk why.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks

Comment: @That'sLife, the point you're struggling with seems to be coming from the fact that Zorn's Lemma doesn't give us much in the way of specific information. *All* we know is that there is ***at least one*** maximal element of the partial order. As an element of the partial order, such a maximal element $f$ is necessarily a bijection $A\times A\to A$ for some subset $A$ of $B,$ but any other properties we would like $f$ to have (such as being a bijection $B\times B\to B$) must be proved, and cannot simply be assumed because it seems like it "should" be true, intuitively.

Comment: (continued) Another thing that may be leading you astray is that you seem to be thinking of such a maximal element as being the result of some sort of transfinite process. While there's nothing wrong with considering it that way, we know **nothing** *a priori* about the specific details of such a transfinite process, and so we shouldn't try to draw conclusions about how it might end up simply from the heuristic observation that a transfinite process could reach that maximal element. Instead, we're forced to rely on maximality alone to draw further conclusions.

Comment: @CameronBuie I know in Zorn's Lemma framework , we can't except an explicit construction. But we have an intuition about for the (transfinite) recursion process works in general.  Here I wanted to understand / get an intuition about how the (transfinite) recursion process may look like if we start with an arbitrary element. I have resolved the issue now.

Comment: @That'sLife, I'm glad you've gotten your head around it! Shinrin-Yoku's example is a very good one, though it wasn't presented the way I would have. Instead, I would have noted that if $f$ is a bijection from $\bigl(\omega\smallsetminus\{\emptyset\}\bigr)\times\bigl(\omega\smallsetminus\{\emptyset\}\bigr)$ to $\omega\smallsetminus\{\emptyset\},$ then we can only add one more element in the codomain $\omega$ while retaining a bijection, but would need infinitely-many more elements to extend the domain to $\omega\times\omega.$

Comment: @CameronBuie Using transfinite recursion, we might never come up with an explicit maximal element. You are right. But the transfinite process provide us some insight in accepting existence of a maximal element.

Comment: @CameronBuie I really quickly got that point. But I my query was different. It was meant to get  some intuition of the undergoing transfinite process.

Comment: I see! That had not been clear to me before. I've added an answer that will hopefully make it clearer why trying to think of it as a transfinite process need not even be accurate, so isn't productive.

Comment: @CameronBuie “I wouldn’t have presented it…” remember that in my answer I answer the sum of cardinals case not the product. Anyhow the OP keeps changing their question, if you look at the first edition my answer perfectly answered the question.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku, that's what I mean, actually. I would have addressed the product case, rather than the sum. However, that's a matter of taste, more than anything else. I don't mean to criticize the *quality* of your answer at all, and I applaud the fact that you continued to try to clarify, despite the fact that the OP moved the goalposts on you so many times!

Comment: OP also says they "quickly got that point" to you, that is a blatant lie, as is shown by thier answer they did not, and refused to understand my answer. It is why I stopped making any further edits. @CameronBuie

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku I would appreciate if you don't engage in personal banter. It is distasteful for me to engage in personal banter.

Answer (score 1):

Given sets $S$ and $T,$ I will denote the class of all functions from $S$ to $T$ by ${}^{S}T.$ I will similarly denote the class of all functions from some subset of $S$ to some subset of $T$ by ${}^{[S]}[T].$ The latter is non-standard notation, as far as I'm aware. It is not difficult to prove that if $S$ and $T$ are sets, then so is ${}^ST,$ and from there, one can prove that ${}^{[S]}[T]$ is likewise a set. Finally, for any set $A,$ I will denote the "successor set" of $A$ by $s(A):=A\cup\{A\}.$

Consider $B=s(\omega):=\omega\cup\{\omega\}.$ Then $$H:=\left\{f\in{}^{[B\times B]}[B]\mid f:A\times A\to A\textrm{ is a bijection for some }A\subseteq B\right\}.$$ Indeed, observing that $\emptyset$ is a function that is readily a bijection $\emptyset\times\emptyset\to\emptyset,$ we have that $\emptyset\in H,$ even though I didn't make it explicit that $\emptyset\in H$ from the definition, the way that Enderton did.

The next thing worth noting is something that you already observed, which is that if $A$ is a finite, non-empty subset of $B,$ then there is no $f\in H$ such that $f:A\times A\to A.$ However, that doesn't mean that $H=\{\emptyset\}.$

Indeed, we can use the following classical construction of a bijection $\omega\times\omega\to\omega.$

- Partition $\omega\times\omega$ into sets of ordered pairs as follows. Given $n\in\omega,$ and let $$A_n:=\bigl\{\langle k,m\rangle\in\omega\times\omega\mid k\cup m=n\bigr\}.$$ So, for any element of $A_n,$ we know that neither of its coordinates is greater than $n,$ and at least one of its coordinates is equal to $n.$ It can be shown that the sets $A_n$ are pairwise disjoint, and that their union is all of $\omega\times\omega.$
- It can be shown that for each $n\in\omega,$ $|A_n|=2n+1.$
- Define the relation $\sqsubset$ on $\omega\times\omega$ by $\langle k_1,m_1\rangle\sqsubset\langle k_2,m_2\rangle$ iff either (1) $m_1=m_2$ and $k_1\in k_2$ or (2) $k_1=k_2$ and $m_2\in m_1.$ It can readily be verified that the restriction of $\sqsubset$ to any of the sets $A_n$ is an order relation on $A_n,$ and so a well-order relation (that we might think of as the "clockwise" order).
- Now, we construct a bijection $\omega\times\omega\to\omega$ by recursion, first letting $g(\emptyset,\emptyset)=\emptyset.$ If we have just defined $g(k,\emptyset)$ for some $k\in\omega,$ then we define $g\bigl(\emptyset,s(k)\bigr):=s\bigl(g(k,\emptyset)\bigr).$ If we have just defined $g(k,m)$ for some $\langle k,m\rangle\in\omega\times\omega$ such that $m\neq\emptyset,$ then letting $n=k\cup m,$ we have that $\langle k,m\rangle\in A_n,$ but is not the $\sqsubset$-greatest element of $A_n,$ so letting $\langle k',m'\rangle$ be the immediate $\sqsubset$-successor of $\langle k,m\rangle$ in $A_n,$ we define $g(k',m'):=s\bigl(g(k,m)\bigr).$

The gist is that we work our way through all of $\omega\times\omega$ by working through the sets $A_n$ in numerical order, and working through the individual elements of each set $A_n$ in "clockwise order." I leave it to you to verify that the function $g$ thus defined is, in fact, a bijection $\omega\times\omega\to\omega.$ (You can even work out a formula, if you want.)

However, there are several observations about $g$ that are much more relevant!

1. $g\in H.$
2. $g$ is a *maximal* element of $H$ with respect to set inclusion.
3. If $f\in H$ such that $f\subseteq g,$ then either $f=g$ or $f$ is the restriction of $g$ to $\emptyset\times\emptyset$ or to $\{\emptyset\}\times\{\emptyset\}.$
4. The largest chain in $H$ including $g$ is of cardinality $3.$

Consequently, there need be no infinite process occurring in $H$ to produce a maximal element at all!

Comment: Your construction of g is impressive. Does 'there need be no transfinite process occuring in H' is implicit in my answer (See from Beginning of 4th para "Suppose B=ω. Clearly ϕ∈H. ........ Upto first 6 lines of 5th para[so t is maximal element of H] ) or am I missing some important point in your final argument . Asking for just to confirm my understanding.But surely g is very special construction which shows that we cannot get any $f \in H$ s.t. $f \subset g$.

Comment: You were quite right about your answer above suggesting that no transfinite process need occur to produce a maximal element. Indeed, the function $t$ that you mentioned could easily have a similar property to my function $g,$ in that it may be minimal among non-empty functions in $H.$ However, one certainly *could* build one through a transfinite process. For example, we could start with a bijection of [powers of two] x [powers of two] to [powers of two]. We could then extend that to include powers of 3, then powers of 5, 7, 11, etc.

Comment: (cont'd) *How* to extend it is more complicated than simple disjoint union, but it *is* possible to make each of these extensions, in turn. However, the union of all of the functions in this chain would *still* not be maximal in $H.$ We could then proceed through numbers that are products of powers of 2 and 3 only, then 2 and 5 only, then 2 and 7 only, etc. Once done, we could continue along those lines, extending the domains and range by an infinite set infinitely-many times, and repeating that sort of process infinitely-many times. Very transfinite, indeed! Only $0$ and $1$ would be missed.

Comment: Slight correction: Each time I said "powers" above, I should have specified *positive* powers. That's how we end up missing $1.$ It should be obvious why $0$ would be missed.

Comment: I was not expecting an answer with rigour. Some insight into to process. From Your answer along with your the comments, I get an essence of the whole situation. That was what I was expecting. Thank you for your elaborate answer.

Comment: I missed a very obvious error. It should be corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This answer focuses on the sum of cardinals case, the product case is slightly different but the same example works, and is left as an exercise.

Letting $K=\mathbb{N}$. Applying Zorn’s lemma we get the existence of a maximal element under that order, all Zorn’s lemma says is that a maximal element *exists* and nothing more, the maximal element could for example be $(\mathbb{N},f)$ but it could also be $(\mathbb{N}-\{0\},g)$(Checking this is a maximal element is not hard), so Zorn’s lemma gives *no guarantee* that the maximal element is $(K,f)$. Luckily, by the way the order is constructed it is not hard to prove that the maximal element must be of the form $(K-F, h)$  where $F$ is some finite set.

**Edit:** You don't seem to be convinced that $(\mathbb{N}-\{0\}, g)$ where, $g: \mathbb{N}-\{0\} \to 2\times (\mathbb{N}-\{0\})$ is a bijection, is a maximal element. To prove that it is maximal element note that there can not exist a bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\to2\times \mathbb{N}$ extending $g$, because $2\times\mathbb{N}$ has two more elements than $2\times(\mathbb{N}-\{0\}$), while $\mathbb{N}$ has **only** one more element than $\mathbb{N}-\{0\}$.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143290/discussion-on-answer-by-shinrin-yoku-for-infinite-cardinal-kappa-kappa); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.